# Symfony3 - @UniqueEntity is not working

Tags: php, symfony, unique, unique-constraint

I can´t find the way to handle the database error when I intend to save data @uniqueConstrainst of my database allow.
The problem is that my @UniqueEntity don´t handle the error before the database error displays.

This is my code

```
    * @ORM\Table(name="persona_idioma", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="persona_idioma_unique",columns={"id_persona","id_idioma"})},indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IX_Relationship11", columns={"id_idioma"}), @ORM\Index(name="IX_Relationship12", columns={"id_persona"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PersonaIdiomaRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"idPersona", "idIdioma"},
 *     errorPath = "idPersona", 
 *     message="mensaje"
 *       
 * )
```

Updated: I have just added the columns of the entity

```
/**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Persona
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Persona",inversedBy="idiomas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_persona", referencedColumnName="id_persona")
     * })
     */
    private $idPersona;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Idioma
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Idioma")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_idioma", referencedColumnName="id_idioma")
     * })
     */
    private $idIdioma;
```

And the controller where the entity is persisted

```
$formulario->handleRequest($request);

    if ($formulario->isSubmitted() && $formulario->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($persona);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('persona_edit', array('id_persona' => $persona->getIdPersona()));
    }

    return $this->render('persona/new_edit.html.twig', [
                'formulario' => $formulario->createView(),
    ]);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where the entity is validated?

Comment: I have just added the columns indeed

Comment: I rather mean: Are you using the validator to validate the entity before persisting it?

Comment: No, how can I do that ?

Comment: Can you share the controller action where the entity is persisted? Also, are you using service auto-wiring for your controllers?\

Comment: How can I do to do $form->handleRequest and then my form would not be valid?

Comment: I have just edited again

Comment: Are you checking if the form is valid? `$form->isValid()`

Comment: I don´t know about the auto-wiring, how can i checked it?

Comment: I have just checked and my service autowire is set to true , i change this and the error continues

Comment: simple question - did you clear your cache after you added the `@UniqueEntity` annotation? ;)

Comment: Yes I cleared my cache

Comment: To be sure: you know that UniqueEntity constraint does not come from the same namespace as other constraints, right ? The namespace is Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity while other constraints namespace is Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints

Comment: Yes, no problem with that

Comment: Did you put use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity; ?

Comment: Yes, I use what you have said

Comment: I think the `fields:` are **not** property names but column names ... so instead of `idPersona` you'd need to reference `id_person` aka the given name for the `@ORM\JoinColumn`. Did you try that? Don't forget to clear the cache after changing the annotation!

Comment: Yes, I tried putting the original name of the column in the db but continues the same issue

Comment: Have you tried placing a debug statement in `UniqueEntityValidator::validate`

Comment: YES , I am now thinking that it is a symfony bug

Comment: Have the same problem, looks like a bug to me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as u, I changed my code from:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username", "email"}, message="This value is already taken")
 */
```

to:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="This username is already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="This email is already taken")
 */
```

It's strange but it worked for me. Just give me sign if I helped u.

Comment: I don't know if this works , but a need the unique entity with the two fields at the same time